# PHP Error_Log script not found:<script></script>

Tags: php, error-log, error-list

I can see this error in my error log, but it is not exactly easy for me to troubleshoot. I have looked back and have been receiving this error for the past few months. I have no record of making a change to the websites code the day the error started appearing. Notes about my website is hosted by BlueHost - Cloud Hosting, the website uses the WordPress CMS.

Example from my error_log file:

```
...

[01-Mar-2017 17:02:33 UTC] script not found:<script> </script>
[01-Mar-2017 18:13:24 UTC] script not found:<script> </script>
[01-Mar-2017 20:58:27 UTC] script not found:<script> </script>
```

Anyone have any idea what may be causing this to appear in my error_log?

Comment: improved redability

Comment: Can you share your markup?

Comment: This is a pretty standard WordPress installation. You want me to share my entire WordPress installation markup? My main question is: Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: I contacted BlueHost and they said, that it is probably a minor error and that they don't know what it is or how to resolve the error. Thanks BlueHost. :)